# What's wrong with this code for filtering data?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

```
Private Sub txtSearchJobNo_AfterUpdate()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset, strCriteria As String
strCriteria = "[A_JOBNO]=" & txtSearchJobNo
Me.FilterOn = False
'-- Me.Filter = strCriteria
Me.FilterOn = True
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.FindFirst(strCriteria"[A_JOBNO]=" & txtSearchJobNo)
If rst.NoMatch Then
MsgBox "No entry found"
Else
Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
End If
End Sub
```

Above is the code I am trying to use for filtering data on my form based on the input from the user into a textbox.Nothing absolutely happens.

Comment: Are you sure A_JobNo is a numeric field? BTW the way you are working with filters and finds is not a good idea.

Comment: A_JobNo is nvarchar(15) in sql db and stores values like this: "E2Y9038" whereas in the form it is selected as "E-2Y-9038" to be displayed on the form.Also rst.NoMatch=false on debugging.And what is the better way then?

Comment: Atleast you can tell what is my problem?

Comment: Yes, I explained below, with code.

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes for text fields.

```
Private Sub txtSearchJobNo_AfterUpdate()
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset, strCriteria As String

   strCriteria = "[A_JOBNO]=" & txtSearchJobNo
   Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
   rst.FindFirst(strCriteria"[A_JOBNO]='" & txtSearchJobNo) & "'"

   If rst.NoMatch Then
      MsgBox "No entry found"
   Else
      Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
     'Filter here or bookmark, not both
   End If
End Sub
```